# JQuery Add/Removing Classes on Window Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to write a small script which adds/removes classes based off of window with,

any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 500) {
     $('.single-post-rating').removeClass('col-xs-3');
     $('.single-post-rating').addClass('col-xs-12');
     $('.guide-excerpt').removeClass('col-xs-9');
     $('.guide-excerpt').addClass('col-xs-12');
    }
    else {
     $('.single-post-rating').addClass('col-xs-3');
     $('.single-post-rating').removeClass('col-xs-12');
     $('.guide-excerpt').addClass('col-xs-9');
     $('.guide-excerpt').removeClass('col-xs-12');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after the viewport width.

You can access that with

```
var viewPortWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

*As an aside, you can accomplish a lot of good responsive layouts through CSS media queries alone*.

Comment: Totally. Everything else in my document is through media queries, this part is just tricky because I'm using Bootstrap columns, but adding an extra smaller one.

Comment: Is there anyway you could through your example in my code? I'm not too certain how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue on this path, this is one of the best solution to manage the width of the window:
add a control css class, with min-with property and assign that class to your container

css:

```
.mediaquerycontrol {
    min-width: 0px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

    .mediaquerycontrol {
        min-width: 992px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    .mediaquerycontrol {
        min-width: 768px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

    .mediaquerycontrol {
        min-width: 1200px;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="container mediaquerycontrol">
...
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    var pageWidth = parseInt($(".mediaquerycontrol").css("min-width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''))

    if (pageWidth  < 500) {
     $('.single-post-rating').removeClass('col-xs-3').addClass('col-xs-12');
     $('.guide-excerpt').removeClass('col-xs-9').addClass('col-xs-12');
    }
    else {
     $('.single-post-rating').addClass('col-xs-3').removeClass('col-xs-12');
     $('.guide-excerpt').addClass('col-xs-9').removeClass('col-xs-12');
    }
  });
</script>
```

but my advice is to use the features of bootstrap, and if you need smaller columns then you can increase the number of columns by default (eg from 12 to 24 if you're using the 2.3.2 version)

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html